# jQuery appendTo with attributes from JSON

Tags: jquery, appendto

```
$.each(tools, function (i, tool) {
    $("<img>", tool).appendTo($toolbar);
});

//define toolset (JSON, e.g. from database)...
var tools = [{
    "data-id": 1,
    alt: "sun",
    title: "sun",
    src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Sunny.png",
    "data-description": "sun in photo"
}, {
    "data-id": 2,
    alt: "snow",
    title: "snow",
    src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Thermometer_Snowflake.png",
    "data-description": "snow in photo"
}, {
    "data-id": 3,
    alt: "cloud",
    title: "cloud",
    src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Overcast.png",
    "data-description": "cloud in photo"
}, {
    "data-id": 4,
    alt: "rain",
    title: "rain",
    src: "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Night_Rain.png",
    "data-description": "rain in photo"
}];
```

I am looking at some jQuery that I am seeing for the first time. I see that I believe what happens is for each tool and img tag is created with the appropriate attributes described in the JSON. If that is so I think that is very neat and I am wondering where might this technique be described in more detail perhaps in the manual or API documentation?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: That is actually a good idea. See [this constructor overload](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes) for info on using an object to specify attributes when creating elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code:

```
$.each(tools, function (i, tool) {
    $("<img>", tool).appendTo($toolbar);
})
```

let's part it in blocks:

---

`$.each(tools, function (i, tool) { });` - [jQuery `each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)

this is the same as:

```
for(i = 0; i < tools.length; i++) {
    var tool = tools[i];
}
```

---

`$("<img>", tool)` - [jQuery element creator](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

this is the same as having:

```
$("<img data-id='' src='' alt='' title='' data-description=''>");
```

and fill up with each set of parameters, for example, the first `tool` (the sun) would be:

```
$("<img data-id='1' src='http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Sunny.png' alt='sun' title='sun' data-description='sun in photo'>");
```

which is the same as:

```
$("<img>").attr({
    "data-id": 1,
    "alt": "sun",
    "title": "sun",
    "src": "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Sunny.png",
    "data-description": "sun in photo"
});
```

and the same as

```
$("<img>", {
    "data-id": 1,
    "alt": "sun",
    "title": "sun",
    "src": "http://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/iconsland-weather/PNG/48x48/Sunny.png",
    "data-description": "sun in photo"
});
```

which is exactly what the `$("<img>", tool)` is all about

---

`appendTo($toolbar);` - [jQuery `appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/)

simply append the result for each object in the `tools` array, into the `$toolbar` which might be a simple `<div>`